# Is there any way to make Brackets' Live Preview feature work on Meteor projects?

Tags: meteor, less, adobe-brackets

I am styling a project built on Meteor and using LESS. I use Brackets for styling because its Live Preview feature makes working with CSS a lot quicker and more pleasurable, but by Meteor's nature it doesn't seem possible to use this feature.

Every little change I make on the code has to be detected by Meteor, who will in turn refresh the project on the browser for me, and this process is now taking anything between 5 and 10 seconds, which is ***entirely too much***.

Does anyone know if it's possible to work on "live" CSS/LESS, using Brackets, in a Meteor project, without having to wait for Meteor to notice my changes and take its sweet time to refresh the whole thing for me?

Or at the very least least if there's anything I can do to shorten the time Meteor takes to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible unless the developers of Brackets go an extra mile and implement a specific support tailored for Meteor.

Brackets works on top of raw CSS and HTML files and uses Chrome Dev Tools API to manipulate the page.

Meteor doesn't send raw files to the client. HTML templates in Meteor get compiled to JS DSL and CSS is concatenated and sent in a manipulated form, too.

Bracket's live preview feature would work only with quick page layout prototyping and will not play well with any modern front-end tool chain that involves compiling pages and stylesheets or preprocessing.